# Windows ToolBar-dockable application

Tags: c#, .net, dockable

How to create a windows toolbar-dockable application - like [Winamp Desk Band](http://www.winamp.com/plugins/details/82271) - in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## C# does Shell, Part 3

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx

## AppBar using C#

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AppBar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create an **AppBar**.

I suggest you first check out the AppBar implementation included with [the Genghis package](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/genghis/). I couldn't say if it's any good since I never used it, but it looks promising.

Manually, you would have to use a few Win32 API calls to reserve/free the screen space and achieve the effect you're looking for, as detailed in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/AppBar.aspx).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As a commercial alternative, see the ready-to-use [ShellAppBar](http://www.ssware.com/shlobj/shlobj.htm) component which supports all cases and secnarios such as taskbar docked to left,right,top,bottom edge, support for multiple monitors, drag-docking, autohide , etc etc.